# Getting Choi-matrix of a subsystem

Tags: programming, qiskit, quantum-operation

In Qiskit, for a given `QuantumCircuit` object, you can compute its Choi-matrix via the corresponding `Choi` object, for example:

```
myCircuit = QuantumCircuit(q1,q2)
myChoi = Choi(myCircuit)
```

My problem is, that code gives the Choi-matrix describing the whole system, but I'm interested to one subsystem, say the one associate to q1.
What can I do?

I would like to do something like

```
myChoi = Choi(myCircuit, q1)
```

Comment: I dont think that's possible at the moment. You can explain your use case and request the feature here: https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-terra/issues/new?labels=type%3A+feature+request&template=FEATURE_REQUEST.md

Comment: I remember you asked a question on how to do this analytically for the process matrix. I am still not sure that it exactly _is_ possible, i.e. this is the best description of 'what happens' to q1 and q1 only. Do you have some thoughts on this?

Comment: I can't see why it wouldn't be possible. For sure, I can get an exact estimation of that Choi-matrix, via some method based on process tomography.